# Finding The Second Fundamental Form

Tags: differential-geometry, index-notation

Using the following $$L_{i}^{ j}=-L_{ik}g^{kj}$$ we can calculate the  second fundamental form.

But in exercise is see that from matrix multiplication it is $$L_{i}^{ j}=-g^{kj}L_{ik}$$ does it commute?

In the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: What is $L^j_i$?  What is $L_{ik}$?  What is $g^{kj}$?  Are you working in the context of surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or in the context of an arbitrary submanifold in a general Riemannian $n$-manifold?  This question is not clear as currently phrased.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$ edited

Comment: Of course they commute, they are real numbers (nothing to do with $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: If you consider the *matrix* $L$ whose $ji$-entry is $L_i^j$ and the *matrices* $A$ (whose $ik$ entry is $L_{ik}$) and $B$ (whose $kj$ entry is $g^{kj}$), then you have the matrix equation $L=-AB$. And, no, you can't switch the order on that matrix multiplication. By the way, if $G$ is the matrix of the first fundamental form, then of course we have $B=G^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that $L_{ij}$ are the components of the second fundamental form and that therefore $L : T_{p}M \mapsto T_{p}M$ and $\mathcal{L} : T_{p}M \times T_{p} M \mapsto \mathbb{R}$? If so then $L_{ij} = \mathcal{L}(x_i
, x_j )$. What you have then aritten above is the standard way of raisign and lowering the indeices using the metric and the correct way to write it is $L_{ij} = \sum_{k} g_{ik}L^{k}_{j}$.